# Multiple preparations of the same density operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

In complement EIII on density operators in Quantum Mechanics by Cohen-Tannoudji, it is stated that

> An ensemble of pure states $|\psi_k\rangle$ with probabilities $p_k$ leads to a single density operator $\rho$, but the reverse is not true in general: the same density operator can be interpreted as several different statistical mixtures of pure states. For instance, in a space of states with dimension $N$, a statistical mixture of the $N$ states of a given basis $|u_n\rangle$ with the same probability $1/N$ leads to a density operator that is the unit operator, divided by $N$; but the same operator may be obtained with a statistical mixture of the kets of any other basis $|v_n\rangle$. These various ensembles lead to the same probabilities $P(a_n)$, and cannot be distinguished by measuring these probabilities. This situation is sometimes described as the “multiple preparations” of the same density operator.

The first part of this argument sounds plausible: that multiple statistical mixtures of pure states would lead to the same density operator. However, I don't quite follow the example. If you write out a density matrix, haven't you already chosen a basis? Additionally, to calculate the probabilities of measuring different eigenvalues of an observable, you also need to be explicit about the choice of basis. So, why would you be confused about the basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The density matrix is a linear operator $\rho \colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ (the name "matrix" is historical). As operator it exists and can be described independently of the basis, as an object mapping vectors from the Hilbert space, to vectors in the Hilbert space of the problem.
2. You don't need to choose a basis for determining measurement results. The introductory course way of assigning probabilities to eigenvalues is not the whole picture of quantum measurement, but just a special case of more general [projective measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#Projective_measurement) (which again is a special case of [POVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM)). Roughly, you take projection operators (that is operators $\Pi$ with the property $\Pi^2 = \Pi$). These operators project a state vector to a subset of the state space. You assign values to these projectors (or rather ranges of values, e.g. the projection to all states with position between $a$ and $b$, or the projection to all states with negative spin projection along the $x$-axis). Then the Born rule applies for the probability of finding a system described by a state vector $\left|\psi\right>$ in the subspace of the projector: $$ P_k(\psi) = \left< \psi \middle| \Pi_k \middle| \psi \right>. $$
   The elementary measurement rules are recovered by taking the projectors to the eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue, and assigning the eigenvalue as value of the measurement (here in the case of no degeneracy):
   $$ \Pi_i = \left| u_i \right>\left<u_i \right|. $$
   This construction generalizes naturally to density matrices:
   $$ \rho = \sum p_i \left| w_i \right> \left< w_i \right|, \quad P_k(\rho) = \mathrm{tr}\,(\rho \Pi_k) = \sum p_i \left<w_i\middle| \Pi_k \middle| w_i \right> = \sum p_i P_k(u_i). $$
3. So the example becomes clear: The Hilbert space we work in is $N$-dimensional. We have a density matrix $\rho = \frac{1}{N} \mathbf{1}$ – and this can be "prepared" by choosing any basis $\left|u_k \right>$ and putting in each of those states into our box with probability $p_k = 1/N$. No matter what basis we choose, we always get the same operator $\rho$. A (perhaps counter-intuitive) example of that is, that there is no measurement that can distinguish the following two electron beams:

   1. Take a source for electrons that can produce electrons in the spin eigenstates with $m = \pm \frac 1 2$ along the **$x$-axis**, and randomly generate the one or the other every time an electron is emitted.
   2. Take a source for electrons that can produce electrons in the spin eigenstates with $m = \pm \frac 1 2$ along the **$y$-axis**, and randomly generate the one or the other every time an electron is emitted.